# How to reuse java editor in multipage editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-pde

I am in need of creating multipage editor with the java editor in first page. I googled several website but the only  way am seeing is duplicating the java editor by creating our own editor but it will be huge maintenance of code.Is there is any other way to integrate java editor with my custom multipage editor

Updated:

[image]

Comment: The JavaEditor is in an **internal** class and therefore is off limits [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: is there is any other way possible to achieve the solution ?

Comment: i need the functionalities of java editor in my multipage editor.. how can i achieve this..? any suggestion is most welcome..

Comment: @greg-449 : can you please see this question ? could you please help with some ideas ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242139/how-to-display-an-custom-editor-inside-a-form-page