# How to display an custom editor inside a form page?

Tags: editor, jface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Is it possible to display or embed a custom editor inside a form page(form toolkit)? I have created a eclipse plugin where i need to embed a custom editor inside a multi - page form editor.

1. Is it possible?
2. If possible, How?

Am a newbie in eclipse plugin, This question may look easy for you people. Please help with this. I have searched a lot in internet but i couldn't find any perfect solution.

Updated :

[image]

Comment: The New Plugin Project wizard will create example code for this - 'Plugin with a multi-page editor'

Comment: @greg-449 : Thanks for the response,But the example will embed the editor for the whole page.In my case I need some other widgets like label,button text boxes inside the same page where editor is embeded.

Comment: I have never seen anything do that

Comment: so it is not possible to embed a editor like this ?

Comment: can we embed it inside a section ?

Comment: `MultiPageEditorPart` only has support for the editor on a separate page. You might be able to do this elsewhere but you would have to study the source.

Comment: You can try using StyledText with auto-complete support and code highlighting in any Composite and in your case a Form. This is as close as you might get to an embedded editor.